# Firebase addEventListener not working with "import" in js file

Tags: javascript, firebase

When I add an "import" from one js file to another the EventListener refuses to work! Editing out the import line makes the event work! Could someone please help? I also struggled with the importing of a function so would appreciate it if someone could take a look and check my code.
Hoping an answer is out there. Thanks

```
index.js

export function lookupRegNumber() {
    var plate = document.getElementById("regNumber").value;
      console.log("Selected" + " - " + plate);
      {const docsSnap = getDocs(exAddCarRef );
        docsSnap.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.data());
      })}
   }
```

```
data.js

import { lookupRegNumber } from "./index.js";

const getRegNo = document.getElementById('lrn');
getRegNo.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("test");
  lookupRegNumber();
})
```

```
report.html

<table class="table table-success " id="add-item">
      <tr><td>Registration No:</td><td><input type="text"style="text-transform:uppercase" id="regNumber"></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td><button id="lrn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search Reg No</button></td></tr> 
</table>

<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refuses to work"?  Please edit the question to describe what exactly is not working the way you expect, including all of your debugging details (logs, error messages, and so on). We should be able to reproduce the behavior using the instructions you provide.

Comment: Typo. [Use a validator](https://validator.nu/). You get a script from a **SouRCe** not a **SCReensaver**.

Comment: Apologies! The above script does not function, ie no console log message and lookupRegNumber() does not run.  By deleting the import line and clicking the button I get the console log message, of course the lookupRegNumber() does not run as it wants the imported function from index.js

Comment: I have amended the report.html script and checked via a validator as suggested, there were some errors which have now been amended. However with the "import" line in the data.js file seems to prevent the event listener from firing (no console log output), however delting that particular line of script allows the event listener to fire! I need to import the function (I believe) so that I can retrieve data from the firestore database using getDocs. Please can you point me in the right direction. I am new to firebase and trying to learn. THANKS!